# Is it possible to reload lvm.conf without reboot?

Tags: configuration, lvm, ssd, reboot

I enabled `issue_discards` in `lvm.conf` file on machine with ssd and I'd like to perform `blkdiscard` on one of logical volumes. Can i do that without rebooting machine? I'm able to unmount physical volume along with all logical volumes stored on this particular ssd but I'd prefer to avoid system reboot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the default comments in my `lvm.conf`, the `issue_discards` option only controls what happens to the freed space when you run `lvreduce` or `lvremove`, nothing else:

```
# Configuration option devices/issue_discards.
# Issue discards to PVs that are no longer used by an LV.
# Discards are sent to an LV's underlying physical volumes when the LV
# is no longer using the physical volumes' space, e.g. lvremove,
# lvreduce.
```

It is confirmed by [this message on linux-lvm mailing list by RedHat's Mike Snitzer](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2012-December/msg00002.html):

> lvm.conf's issue_discards doesn't have any affect on the kernel (or
>   underlying device's) discard capabilities.  It only controls whether
>   discards are issued by lvm for certain lvm operations (like when an LV
>   is removed).

So, if the underlying SSD supports TRIM or other method of discarding data, you should be able to use `blkdiscard` on it or any LVs placed on it just fine.

In other words, if you enable `issue_discards`, you can achieve the discarding of a LV's contents in two ways:

- run `blkdiscard` on the LV. Example:

`# lvcreate -L 1g vg00
   Logical volume "lvol6" created.
 # blkdiscard -v /dev/vg00/lvol6
 /dev/vg00/lvol6: Discarded 1073741824 bytes from the offset 0`

- just use `lvremove` and LVM does the discarding for you. You don't have to do anything special to make the setting take effect.

`[issue_discards initially disabled]
 # lvremove /dev/vg00/lvol6
 Do you really want to remove active logical volume vg00/lvol6? [y/n]: y
   Logical volume "lvol6" successfully removed
 # vi /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
[set issue_discards to enabled]
 # lvcreate -L 1g vg00
   Logical volume "lvol6" created.
 # lvremove /dev/vg00/lvol6
 Do you really want to remove and DISCARD active logical volume vg00/lvol6? [y/n]: y
  Logical volume "lvol6" successfully removed`

Note the added `... and DISCARD ...` in the message of the `lvremove` command.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting `/dev/mapper/data-cache: BLKDISCARD ioctl failed: Operation not supported` whereas I'm pretty sure I had no problem with running blkdiscard on entire partition/drive. It's Samsung 850 pro. `hdparm -I /dev/sdi` says `Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)`. I remember setting up full trim support up to `btrfs` level on old installation but this time i didn't bother until now.

Comment: Oh i forgot to mount dm-crypt with `discard` enabled

Comment: From the information you initially supplied, I would have needed a really wizardly crystal ball to see that :-) Good to hear that you found the cause.

Comment: How can one discard a volume that was already removed? Basically discard all unused PEs in a PV.